# Fitting multiple models to a noisy measurement

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, markov-chain-montecarlo, dirichlet-process

I have measured a quantity for a set of data contains couple of thousands objects. Since the measurement is very noisy, I need a set of data contains a lot of objects. Then I have a model based on the measured quantity which is a function of four free parameters. The problem is that in the data that I am dealing with I can fit more than one model but I am not sure how many model I can fit. 
My first question is: How could I find out **how many models** I need to describe the data? Something like **Dirichlet Gaussian Mixture model** is the way to go or other methods?

My second question: The data is very noisy and using an approach like **Monte Carlo Markov Chain** is not the best option, what are the other options to deal with noisy data and fitting more than one single model to the data?

Comment: Can you explain why 'noisy' implies MCMC is 'not the best option'? I could understand it if you said that noisiness ruled out a particular *model* or class of models ... but MCMC is a class of *algorithms* -- for pretty much any model. e.g. if you think Dirichlet Gaussian Mixture models are suitable ... why would you rule out fitting them via MCMC on the basis that the data  are noisy? I find the implications of the comment confusing, to say the least. It makes me wonder whether you have conflated MCMC with some particular subset of models.

Comment: @Glen_b Because I have tried to use MCMC on the simulated data with the properties of real data and get constraints on the free parameters but I wasn't getting what I expected. Maybe I have not implemented the MCMC method properly but I was also wondering what are the obstacles in using MCMC?!

Comment: Now I'm pretty certain you are conflating model issues (and perhaps implementation issues as well) with MCMC. If you fit one model via MCMC and it turns out that it's unsuitable, that implies a problem with the model (or possibly your implementation) rather than a problem with MCMC. What is it you think MCMC consists of?

Comment: @Glen_b well, it is consist of surfing the parameter space with sampling data, however it might not surf the parameter space properly due to the sampling method.

Comment: But as I already pointed out, your proposed solution could be implemented via MCMC (non-nested models - even with entirely different parameter-sets - can be fitted and moved between using appropriate forms of MCMC for example). So it's not clear how that's an MCMC issue rather than a problem with either the model or a particular implementation. Certainly one can have an issue where a particular implementation has such problems exploring the parameter space ("getting stuck" in some subset), and if it's a situation where they're difficult to avoid, that would suggest looking at alternatives.

Comment: @Glen_b how could I pin down in my real data how many models I need to fit?

Comment: @Glen_b what are the alternatives for the case of getting stuck in the subset?

Comment: That's much too general a question for comments. In one way or another, you pursue a different sampling scheme, but that could imply a host of things, anything from integrating a parameter out/sampling in blocks to (for example) replacing Gibbs with some form of Metropolis-Hastings (or *whatever-you-did* with *whatever-else*). Sometimes a simple reparameterization works wonders! It may require investigation of the specific issues leading to the poor behavior. MCMC is (generally) not some simple 'push the button and it just works' tool; you design a sampler to suit your particular situation.